# Decorate subclass method

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

Suppose I there is a class `Foo`. I wrote a decorator `deco` I want to apply to some of the methods of class `Foo`. Since `Foo` is imported from a library, I decided to subclass it as `Bar`. Now, the only thing I need to do is to add the decorator to some methods of `Foo`.

```
class Bar(Foo):

    @deco
    def aMethod(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().aMethod(*args, **kwargs)
```

Since I don't need to modify the code of `aMethod`, is there a simpler way to decorate it, without needing to explicitly having to call `super()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can monkeypatch `Foo` by replacing the methods with the decorated version:

```
Foo.aMethod = deco(Foo.aMethod)
```

Decorator syntax is just syntactic sugar, after all, `deco` is just a callable whose result replaces the decorated function:

```
@deco
def aMethod(...):
    ....
```

is effectively translated to:

```
def aMethod(....):
    ...
aMethod = deco(aMethod)
```

Alternatively, if you prefer to still use a subclass, do the same thing in the body of the class:

```
class Bar(Foo):
    aMethod = deco(Foo.aMethod)
```

In Python 2, you'd need to unwrap the function first:

```
Foo.aMethod = deco(Foo.aMethod.im_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
class Bar(Foo):

    aMethod = deco(Foo.aMethod)   # Foo.aMethod.im_func in Py2.x
```

However, you'll lose the benefit of `super()`; you are essentially "fixing" the parent class at that point instead of waiting until runtime to find it. This is probably fine outside a multiple inheritance scenario, though.